# Android Eclipse ADK Spinner preview size wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I'm placing spinner controls on the graphical layout, but it's ignoring the overall style of the layout and creates huge controls pushing everything out. Running it on my device it looks perfect. Am I doing something wrong? See comparison.

[image: On Eclipse]

[image: On my phone]

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LeftPanel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CURRENT"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Contract 3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Contract 2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Contract 1"
            style="@style/text"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinCurrCon1"
            style="@style/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COMPARISON"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, I'm unable to do a graphical view now, because the spinners are way too big.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you doing everythink alrigh. I had same issue, it may be caused because of deffault width for spinner that is equal to widest item in dropdown, where in designer it doesn't have any items so it's displayed as it is matching parent.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try to work around it.